# Django Login Authentication: I am able to SignUp new user and create new user as well but UNABLE to login as SignUp user

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-login

I'm able to SignUp new user as well but UNABLE to login for handlelogin

```py
def handlelogin(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        loginemail= request.POST['loginemail']
        loginpass = request.POST['loginpass']
        user = authenticate(request, username=loginemail, password=loginpass)
        if user is not None:
            print(loginemail, loginpass)
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, "Successfullly Logged-In")
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Invalid Credentials, Please Try Again")
            return redirect('/')
    
    return HttpResponse('404 - Page Not Find')
```

I have tried print() statement to check and it do work in else statement only, not in if user is not none.

NOTE: THE SYNTAX IN QUESTION IS LITTLE BIT DISTURBED... BUT IN CODE IT IS COMPLTELY FINE.

Comment: The `user` variable is empty that's why it is going inside the else statement. So the question you need to ask is that why your `user` value is empty.The most probable reason is that it cannot find the user with the credentials.

Answer (score 0):

BTW I use [Django forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/) for login and logout users:

views.py:

```py
def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserLoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            user = authenticate(request, username=cd['username'], password=cd['password'])
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                messages.success(request, 'you logged in successfully', 'success')
                return HttpResponseRedirect('dashboard/')
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'username or password is wrong', 'danger')
    else:
        form = UserLoginForm()
    return render(request, 'login.html', {'form': form})


def user_logout(request):
    logout(request)
    messages.success(request, 'you logged out successfully', 'success')
    return HttpResponseRedirect('')
```

forms.py

```py
class UserLoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
```

urls.py

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', user_login),
    path('logout/', user_logout, name='user_logout'),
]
```

Also if you haven't make sign Up page you should make user manually by `python3 manage.py createsuperuser` command.

**For sign Up page:**

urls.py

```py
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('signup/', signup, name='signup'),
]
```

views.py

```py
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
```

forms.py

```py
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Optional.')
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Optional.')
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254, help_text='Required. Inform a valid email address.')
```

Comment: SORRY to inform that ,I still not able to login in user account after using your code and make changes according it. I also gave staff permission from admin panel to make login happen, but i won't work